# Meteor giving error for any command - "Meteor 1.0.1 is not installed and .."

Tags: meteor

I had started learning Meteor a few weeks ago, then had to put it on hold. Now, when I am trying to create a new app by `meteor create myapp` or `meteor --help` or just about anything, I only get the following message:

> Sorry, Meteor 1.0.1 is not installed and could not be downloaded.
>   Please check to make sure that you are online.

There is no problem with my internet connection and I'm not sure what's happening here. I'm on Linux Mint 17. (I think my meteor version is 1.0)

Comment: I am not sure why I was downvoted for this. This is a genuine problem and the meteor site mentions asking questions on StackOverflow. Should this question be framed in a different way?

Comment: Did you try `meteor update`? Meteor released a patch for all Meteor versions due to a dangerous error in the way collections were managed, causing data to disappear under certain circumstances.

Comment: Yes, I did. And I am getting the same message.

Comment: Then, I don't see what else to do but try to reinstall it...

Comment: I got the same problem after "Ctrl+C" while running "meteor create ...".

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at your `.meteor` directory. There has to be a file, called `release`. In this file must be ONLY one line.

```
METEOR@1.0.1
```

So, please check this first and give feedback for more help. :)

Comment: He means `.meteor` directory in the project folder not in home folder.